# 'date' filter without time zone in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is input format:
`yyyy:MM:dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`   (Coming as a string from json service)

Required output format:
`dd-mmm-yyyy`

I have tried with `{{txnDate | date:'dd-mm-yyyy'}}`
but it is not working..

Comment: I´ve never seen dates being returned like this from the server, please confirm to us that format. If you have access to the service, you should preferably fix that format, those `:` separating the date values (year, month and date) are really awkward.

Comment: If the format is not the issue, I see you are aiming to show the month´s name, if that´s the issue you should use this format: `{{txnDate | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}`

Comment: ya..The format in the service is :

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy:MM:dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", timezone = "UTC")

Answer (score 1):

What is the format you are following for your date?

A quick `var a = new Date(); a.toISOString();` in console will give you something like `"2015-02-19T13:30:13.347Z"`. The formatted string you are receiving is not following any standard and I am afraid parsing it to date will result in `Invalid Date` in most of the browsers.

So you can either

1. Get your Date in proper format.
2. Make the best use of whatever is available. You can use `split` to break your string into individual components.

Something like:

`var a  = "yyyy:MM:dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" //Replace with actual string`

`b=a.split(':')` will result in `["yyyy", "MM", "dd'T'HH", "mm", "ss'Z'"]` giving you year and months in `b[0]` and `b[1]`.

For date, you can use `b[2].substring(0,2)` to give you `dd`.

You have all date components(apart from time components, which you don't need anyway) as `string`.

Either use them directly(as a string) or make a date object using these components(since you want month in MMM format).

`$scope.txnDate = new Date(b[0]+'/'+b[1]+'/'+b[2].substring(0,2));`

I am sure there are more ways to optimize this. Comment if this doesn't work for you, will try to elaborate more.

Comment: Hi aniket,
I am returning  return b[2].substring(0,2) +'/'+b[1] + '/' +b[0];

And its the output that I wanted..  :)
Thanks  ..